# Receiving EXC_Breakpoint error before running code

Tags: xcode, testing, fatal-error

I'm working on some `Xcode Testing`.

When I run one of our tests, I'm reciving a `EXC_Breakpoint` error message before the test has begun execution. It's difficult to debug with beakpoints as the error occure before running any code.

I have a feeling it has someting to do with my Xcode setting but can't seem to find the answer.

The last line that we recevie from the output is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do you have a condition or command set in a breakpoint?

Comment: None. at the moment. It seems like the error occurs right before it hits the code